# create boxplots with first element of first row of multiple dataframes

Tags: r, boxplot, lapply

I have a list of dataframes. Each dataframe has 6 rows. I want to create 6 boxplots. The **first** boxplot should take the values of the **first row of the first column**. The **second** boxplot should take the values of the **second row of the first column**, etc.

I want to end up with something like this: [example image](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-VEyLr8-chLc/Ua8u3tjk-AI/AAAAAAAADg8/FXJhTPxYBL0/s400/Fig1.bmp)

Each row should be one boxplot on the horizontal axis.

Right now I have started to do it in a loop, but I think this is not the way to go:

```
for (counter in seq(from = 1, to = wins)) {
    res <- (lapply(mylist, function(x) x[counter,1]))
    boxplot(res)
}
```

The variable `mylist` contains the dataframes. I already use `lapply` to get the first/second/etc. row elements over all dataframes according to the `counter` variable. However, I think I have to also avoid the loop, but this would need a 'better' `lapply` which also loops over the rows of the dataframes in `mylist`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the one liner you want but this works for me

```
# Add a column to each data frame with the row index
for (i in seq_along(mylist)) {
  mylist[[i]]$rowID <- 1:nrow(mylist[[i]])
}

# Stick all the data frames into one single data frame
allData <- do.call(rbind, mylist)

# Split the first column based on rowID
boxList <- split(allData[,1], allData$rowID)

# boxplot likes a list
boxplot(boxList)
```

Comment: cool. looks nice. how can i save the plot to a file on windows?

Comment: i already figured it out. can be seen here: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/saving.htm

Comment: Great, glad it was useful. The link looks comprehensive for plotting (don't forget your dev.off() )

Also forgot, if you wanted to use a label (as in your example image) you can replace the rowID with

`mylist[[i]$rowID <- paste0("stat", 1:nrow(mylist[[i]]))`